# finding polynomial in basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a polynomial function p(t) = t^3 - t^2 + t - 4
in standard basis {1, x, x^2, x^3}

Find the same polynomial function in a different basis B = {1, x-2, (x-2)^2, (x-2)^3}

Currently im creating a matrix and augmenting it as follows:

\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -2 & 4 & -8 &| &-4\\
0 & 1 & -4 & 12 &| &1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -6  &| &-1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1   &| &1\end{array}

Then performing RREF which gives me (2,9,5,1) which should be (-4,1,-1,1) in B.

This is where I get lost, how do I write the polynomial function in B from here?
Is my approach incorrect?

Comment: Your $(2,9,5,1$ look right, your function is $2+9(t-2)+5(t-2)^2+(t-2)^3$. This can also be found by using the Taylor expansion of your polynomial about $t=2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to read your column solution from bottom to top:

$$ 1 [ \ (t-2)^3 \ ] \ + \ 5 [ \ (t-2)^2 \ ] \ + \ 9 [ \ t-2 \ ] \ + \ 2 \cdot 1 \ $$

$$ = \ (t^3 \ - \ 6t^2 \ + \ 12 t \ - \ 8) \ + \ (5t^2 \ -20t \ + \ 20) \ + \ (9t \ - \ 18) \ + \ 2 \ \ .  $$

Comment: thats what I thought at first, but when simplified 1(t−2)^3 + 5(t−2)^2 + 9(t−2) + 2(1) =  t^3 - t^2 + t - 4 which is the original polynomial function in standard basis. Is this expected?

Comment: Yes, you have expressed the original polynomial in $ \ t \ $ in terms of the new basis, thus, $ \ 1 \cdot \mathbf{b_1} \ + \ 5 \cdot \mathbf{b_2} \ + \ 9 \cdot \mathbf{b_3} \ + \ 2 \cdot \mathbf{b_4} \ $ .  By replacing the polynomials of basis $ \ B \ $ with their expressions in $ \ t \ $ , we should recover the polynomial in the "standard" basis, much as we would do to check that a vector in a transformed basis was the same vector in the standard, say, $ \ \mathbf{e_1} \ , \ \mathbf{e_2} \ , \ \mathbf{e_3} \ $ basis, as an example.